# Trouble with C pointers when writing a linked list implementation

Tags: c, pointers

I've been getting back into C programming recently and have some issues with a linked list implementation I'm writing.

Here are my structure definitions:

```
typedef struct linked_list_entry {
    struct linked_list_entry *next;
    struct linked_list_entry *prev;
    void* data;
} linked_list_entry;

typedef struct linked_list {
    uint32 count;
    struct linked_list_entry *first;
    struct linked_list_entry *last;
} linked_list;
```

Here's the code in question:

```
int linked_list_add_entry(linked_list** linked_list, void* data)
{
    linked_list_entry* new = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_entry));
    ...
    DPRINT("last(%p), new (%p)\n", (*linked_list)->last, new);
    (*linked_list)->last->next = new;
    DPRINT("(*linked_list)->last(%p)->next (%p)\n", (*linked_list)->last, (*linked_list)->last->next);
```

With debug output:

```
data-types/linked-list.c:37:linked_list_add_entry(): last(0x7fa497402790), new (0x7fa4974027b0)
data-types/linked-list.c:39:linked_list_add_entry(): (*linked_list)->last(0x7fa4974027b0)->next (0x0)
```

Any idea why the last pointer changes to new and the new pointer changes to `NULL`?

Thanks

Comment: Is ^new^ not a reserve word?

Comment: @ManojKumarRai No, `new` is not a reserved word in C. You're confusing with C++.

Comment: What is the value of `*linked_list` pointer? Add it to the dump. How do you allocate memory for `linked_list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dump you provided shows that the value of `(*linked_list)->last` has changed after you did

```
(*linked_list)->last->next = new;
```

But this line of code does not change `(*linked_list)->last` (at least, it is not supposed to).

Possible explanations for such "magical" behavior include

1. `**linked_list` is not properly allocated. Too little memory is allocated for 
   `**linked_list` object. As a consequence, `*(*linked_list)->last` happens to overlap the memory location of `**linked_list`. This is why the above assignment appears to change `(*linked_list)->last` as well. I.e. due to the aforementioned pointer problem `(*linked_list)->last` and `(*linked_list)->last->next` occupy the same location in memory.

   Things like that can happen, for example, when incorrect (insufficient) amount of memory gets allocated for an object. In that case the problem is in the calling code. It supplies a "broken" list as input.

   How does the calling code allocate memory for `linked_list` itself? Note that in this function you used name `linked_list` for function parameter, thus hiding the name of the type `linked_list`. If you did something like that in the "other" function - the one that allocated `linked_list` object itself - then trying to use `sizeof(linked_list)` in there would have returned incorrect value (size of pointer instead of side of struct type). That would explain underallocation of memory.
2. `(*linked_list)->last` is not a properly initialized pointer. It points into some unpredictable location. As a consequence, `*(*linked_list)->last` happens to overlap the memory location of `**linked_list` etc etc etc (see above).
3. The code you were running is not the code you posted here.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is that I needed to use the struct keyword when using malloc:

```
linked_list_entry* new = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list_entry));
```

Comment: Um... Why? `linked_list_entry` is a perfectly valid type name by itself.

Comment: That can't make any difference with the code you showed. Maybe you were running another version of the code?

Comment: It did, see the following test I just wrote:

    printf("%d vs %d\n", sizeof(linked_list), sizeof(struct linked_list));

    8 vs 24

Strange!

Comment: @Jason The result from your comment is because you've declared a local variable `linked_list` (a pointer, 8 bytes) that shadows the global type name `linked_list`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was just coming to that conclusion myself.

Comment: @Jason: What does `sizeof(linked_list)` have to do with the code you posted? The code you posted does not use either `sizeof(linked_list)` or `sizeof(struct linked_list)`.